# How to get traceback and error message from dead coroutine in lua

Tags: lua, coroutine

How to get traceback and error message from dead coroutine in lua

like normal tracebacks and error from dead coroutine

Answer (score 3):

Using `debug.traceback` and some output of `coroutine.resume`

```
function coroutine.xpcall(co)
  local output = {coroutine.resume(co)}
  if output[1] == false then
    return false, output[2], debug.traceback(co)
  end
  return table.unpack(output)
end

function func()
  error("Crash")
end

local co = coroutine.create(func)    

print(coroutine.xpcall(co)) --Should print error message + the traceback
```

Comment: Putting your own functions in standard modules is generally a bad idea.

Comment: it just for demonstrating change to whatever you want